# Git missing folders and files

Tags: git, egit

I'm using eGit in Eclipse. When pull an existing project in 'workspace1' I see some of the files and folders did not get pulled. However if I change to 'workspace2' and add a new project from the git repository, everything gets pulled in correctly. How can I fix the project in 'workspace1'? My buddy just committed & pushed the changes, it's not files I accidentally deleted in 'workspace1', these are newly added files.

Terminal
git status:

> On branch master
>   Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
>   nothing to commit, working directory clean

git pull:

> Already up-to-date.

Comment: Even though you say that you haven't deleted any files, have you tried to ```checkout``` the remote repository instead of ```pull```ing it?

Comment: I tried to reset master to origin/master as shown [here](http://superuser.com/questions/273172/how-to-reset-master-to-origin-master). which does `git checkout master` . For now I'm just using the other workspace, but I don't want to have to keep switching workspaces every time someone adds new file/folders. Thanks for your help Avalanche.

Comment: Strange I haven't seen such marvelous situation before. What does ```git fetch``` say?

Comment: `git fetch` does not display anything, it seems to execute properly, but the folders/files are no where to be seen. What's really odd about it is it's happening on two separate machines which both pulled the project when it was first committed. I'm hoping it's just a freakish error which will not happen again.

Comment: I am very curious to see what is the actual problem here. Are you sure nobody is amending commits? And I believe you said everything is fine when cloning?

Comment: There are three of us on the project, no one knew what it means to amend commits, I just asked, it's safe to say no one has been amending commits. When I clone everything is fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86821/discussion-between-avalanche-and-krzasteka).